# Drawing graphics in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have seen a lot of questions about making a game using Google app engine. I have run into a problem that I cant seem to find any answers to. What can I actually use to draw my game? Are there any libraries that GAE supports? Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation about graphics support in GAE. However, Google App Engine supports client side graphics via Google Web Toolkit (GWT) 
and Web Browser capabilities (like Canvas, JavaScript or SVG native support).

Link with these and more info:

http://www.tinyline.com/tinylineforgae.pdf

Hope it helps!